# Relative camera pose change from global poses

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

In OpenCV one can estimate the relative rotation and translation of the camera from tracked points using the `recoverPose` function but I am trying to figure out if one can do something similar using the camera position and orientation at two consecutive points in time such as for the ground-truth data in the TUM RGB-D dataset (https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats) where at each timestamp, they provide the camera translation and orientation relative to the global coordinate system.

One can obviously simply subtract the translation values to get a global relative translation, but I want to calculate the relative rotation and translation of the camera from one frame to the next to get comparable results to `recoverPose`.

It is my understanding (from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga40919d0c7eaf77b0df67dd76d5d24fa1) that one can form a matrix to transform from world to camera coordinates through the a 4x4 matrix of which the upper 3x3 represents the global rotation of the camera and the 4th column is its translation from the global origin. Would it be valid to solve my problem simply through matrix multiplication, in other words calculate C = AB' where C is the "relative change" matrix, A is the matrix of the second frame and B is the matrix of the first frame?

The code I currently have for this is

```
from pyquaternion import Quaternion
import numpy as np

quatA = Quaternion(x=x2, y=y2, z=z2, w=w2)
quatB = Quaternion(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1, w=w1)

matA = quatA.transformation_matrix
matA[0,3] = tx2
matA[1,3] = ty2
matA[2,3] = tz2

matB = quatB.transformation_matrix
matB[0,3] = tx1
matB[1,3] = ty1
matB[2,3] = tz1

matC = matA * np.linalg.inv(matB)
```

This code runs but I have no idea if calculates something useful.

If that is completely wrong, what would be the best way to achieve this with OpenCV and Python?